# What are the must know shortcuts in Xcode for faster application development?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

What are the must know shortcuts in Xcode for faster application development?

As a special interest, the Mac shortcut I want to know is the one to open application menus (File, Edit, View, Project, Build etc.,). In Windows, if we type *Alt + F*, the File menu will drop down, and we can navigate through the sub-menus using the arrow keys or typing the letters that are underlined in the menus. How can we do something like that in Mac?

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

For debugging:

1. CMD+SHIFT+I (step into)
2. CMD+SHIFT+O (step)

Building & Running:

1. CMD+B (build project)
2. OPT+CMD+ENTER (debug project)

Comment: Don't forget the all-elusive FN+SHIFT+CMD+ALT+D,M,W (Do my work for me). ps. I'm not a fan of the number of keys involved in many XCode shortcuts.

Comment: @badgerr try `CMD+,` then specify the bindings you want to use

Answer (score 2):

- `Alt` + `Cmd` + `Up` *to toggle between `.h` and `.m` files of a class*
- `Cmd` + `'` *to move to next error or warning*
- `Cmd` + `Shift` + `'` *to move to previous error or warning*
- **Column Selection**: Holding down the option key while dragging allows you to perform a column based selection of text. Might be useful in limited circumstances.

Comment: In Xcode 6, it's `Ctrl` + `Cmd`+ `Up` to toggle between `.h` and `.m`, and `Cmd` + `'` to move to next error or warning.

Answer (score 2):

This is the PDF for all the shortcuts of Xcode

[All Xcode Shorcuts](http://www.bobbis.net/media/Xcode_Shortcuts.pdf)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Control-. to select the next autocompletion, control-/ to select the next placeholder (add shift for previous), control-escape to show autocompletion list.

As a response to your request, if you  have full keyboard access turned on, control-fn-F2 will select the menu bar. Then use the arrows to select an item, and space to choose it.

Comment: Thanks for `control-fn-F2` shortcut. I have been looking for it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

These shortcuts are for Xcode 3.2.x (they may vary from Xcode 3.1.x and other versions):

`Command-double click` on symbol/method name in source code editor > Open the .h file for symbol

`Option-double click` on symbol/method name in source code editor > Open the documentation for symbol

`Command-Option-Shift-F` > `Find Selected Text in Project` (custom shortcut)

I have the following one setup in User Scripts under Code to insert a standard logging call:

[image]
The inserted text is:

```
NSLog(@"[%@ %@]", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

Answer (score 1):

Shift-Command-D (Xcode 3.2) / Shift-Command-O (Xcode 4): Open quickly. Great way to get to the file you want.

Answer (score 1):

"Alt + Cmd + Up to toggle between .h and .m files of a class"

This seems to have been disabled in Xcode 4.  I've not been able to find a way to set it in Bindings, either.  Any hints?

Update:  Just found it.  It has been changed to "Ctrl + Cmd + Up".  It can also be executed with a three finger swipe up or down.

The command, by the way, is called "Jump to Next Counterpart".  I knew that.... :-/

Sometimes it takes a Ph.D. in linguistics to figure computer terminology out.  And I've been doing this since the early 80s.

Comment: Why delete this post?  I know I'm not the only one to look for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Click on any method name in the Xcode.
Then use ALT + CMD + / to insert comments describing the input and return parameters.
This will encourage you to write descriptive comments explaining what is the method supposed to do, thus leading to a more maintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CMD + SHIFT + O` to open the **Open Quickly Dialog**. While you type classes, methods and files will appear matching your entered description. Pressing enter will go to said method, class or file. This greatly improved productivity for me.